# What does video frames per second mean?

Tags: video

I am a newbie to photography and i keep hear 60fps. What does that mean? And how can it have an impact on my videos?

Answer (score 2):

**Basic terminology**

1. A video is a series of frames.
2. **FPS** Is a unit of how many of these frames you use every second. **F**rames **P**er **S**econd. In this specific case you are using 60.
3. You can use those FPS during recording or during playback (or both).

---

As you can use them during recording, during playback or both you have different combinations: R=Recording, P=Playback, E=Effect (Look).

R=60 P=60 E= Live action performance

R=60 P=30 (Less than 60) E=Slow motion

R=30 (Less than 60) P=60 E=Fast motion

But also you need to understand other commonly used values to achieve different looks.

24Fps (Cinematic look)
30Fps (Normal video)
120Fps during recording only (Super slow speed)

Answer (score 1):

Framerate refers to the number of frames (images) per second, as cameras don't record continuously, but in individual discrete periods of time. So the more frames, the smoother your video will look, as it is closer and close to approximating continuous recording. This is limited by your playback device however. A 30fps screen will not gain a benefit from 60fps video played on it.

Framerate is not just important to how smooth footage is however, it is tied to another important part of video, shutter angle. 180 degrees shutter angle on 60fps, is equal to 90 degrees shutter angle on 30 fps. This is because the angle represents the portion of time between one frame to the next where the camera is exposing, and so changing the amount of time between frames, changes the equivalent time shutter angle conveys.

Answer (score -3):

In simple terms, fps basically means how many pictures are shown in a single second of a video. The higher the fps, the better the video quality because there are more frames giving a smoother look. A video with 60fps is considered high-quality and looks very realistic.

Having a higher fps is great for videos with lots of movement, as it makes everything look smoother and reduces blurriness. It can really enhance the overall watching experience for your audience. But keep in mind, recording and playing back videos at 60fps requires more power and storage space, so you'll need to make sure your equipment can handle it.